# Callback argument to LocationClient not getting executed

Tags: android, google-maps

I have this function in a non-activity class

```
public class MapClass extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnItemSelectedListener { ...
protected boolean initiateMap(Context mainAppContext, MapFragment mapFrag) {
    ….
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(mainAppContext, this, this);
    mLocationClient.connect();
    …
    }
```

I am calling this function from my mainactivity and passing its context `mainAppContext` as an object to the func.

My problem is with the last two arguemtns of the `LocationClient` which are actually call backs.

Though I have both of them defined in this same non activity class:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    gotoCurrentLocation();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.onDisconnected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But they never get called over the successful connection? Seems like the `this` is not working as I wanted in this case (I actually saw it from a tutorial).

Can anyone please help me in passing these two callbacks as argument to the `LocationClient` constructor?

Comment: does your `onConnectionFailed` get called? Also where are you getting your context from? if you are in an activity you should be using `this` as context

Comment: myConnection is getting successful so `onConnectionFailed` wont be executing any ways. I am passing the context from the main activity.

Comment: I thought you said onConnected was not getting called?

Comment: yes `onConnected` is not getting called but the connection is successful so `onConnectionFailed` wont get called anyway.

Comment: how do you know the connection is successful? it is probably your context, you should be using `this` for context no some other activity

Comment: i m also using the context variable just a line above in this `isGoogleServiceAvailable(mainAppContext)` and it is working fine.

Comment: I also checked in case of failure `onConnectionFailed` is also not getting called.